# Regex for bracket notation of multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for the regex to get data from a multi-dimensional array.

I have this array bracket notation: `test[0][data1]`. I want to get `test`, `0` and `data1`.

I have made this:

```
new RegExp("([a-z0-9]*)(?:\\[([a-z0-9_]*)\\])", "i")
```

but it stops at `0`.

Comment: repeat the pattern `("([a-z0-9]*)\\[([a-z0-9_]*)\\]\\[([a-z0-9_]*)\\]", "i")`

Comment: use global modifier (g) with case insensitive modifier (i), i think that will help

Comment: If you have just 2 values inside square brackets, try [`/([a-z0-9]+\w*)\[(\w+)]\[(\w+)]/i`](https://regex101.com/r/nA9fG6/1). However, you can just use a substring method to get the first part, and then split the second with `][` after removing the first and last brackets.

Comment: My answer originally had an infinite loop in it. Be sure to see the updated one. Also I've added a fiddle link for you to test / play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to loop through each result.

```
var regex = /([a-z0-9_]*)(?:\[([a-z0-9_]*)\])/ig;
var str = "test[0][data1]";
var match;
var first = false;
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if(!first) console.log(match[1]);
  console.log(match[2]); //Or whatever you would like to do with the found result
}
```

This will result in

```
test
0
data1
```

The advantage to this approach over just extending the regex, is that you can do this for as many items in brackets. For example if using the above

```
var str = "test[0][data1][elephant][sandyBeach][hall]"
```

would result in

```
test
0
data1
elephant
sandyBeach
hall
```

If however you needed to do this approach for a string that contained more than one expression you would need to catch this, and then reset the `first` variable to true.

```
var regex = /([a-z0-9_]*)(?:\[([a-z0-9_]*)\])/ig;
var str = "test[0][data1] test[elephant] rhino[walrus]";
var match;
var first = true;
while((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if(match[1] != null && match[1] != '') {
    if(!first) console.log('');
    console.log(match[1]);
  }
  console.log(match[2]);
  first = false;
}
```

result:

```
test
0
data1

test
elephant

rhino
walrus
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnareChops/wy2c580s/) *be sure to enable jQuery*